# New df column that is current df1 value divided by df2 value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider these 2 dataframes:

**df1 - Nationally observed mpgs**

```
state   make    model   fuel    mpg
FL  honda   fit diesel  43
FL  honda   fit gas 33
FL  vw  golf    diesel  48
FL  vw  golf    gas 35
FL  ford    fiesta  diesel  40
FL  ford    fiesta  gas 36
FL  toyota  corolla diesel  44
FL  toyota  corolla gas 38
```

**df2 -CAFE standards**

```
make    model   fuel    mpg
honda   fit diesel  43
honda   fit gas 33
vw  golf    diesel  48
vw  golf    gas 35
ford    fiesta  diesel  40
ford    fiesta  gas 36
toyota  corolla diesel  44
toyota  corolla gas 38
nissan  sentra  diesel  39
nissan  sentra  gas 29
```

I want to make a new column in df1['avg'] that is the observed mpg divided by the CAFE Std for make, model, fuel.

Here is the approach I was trying by brute force:

```
make_list = ['ford', 'nissan']
model_list = ['focus', 'sentra']
fuel_list = ['gas', 'diesel']

df3 = df2.loc[df2['make'].isin(make_list)]
df3 = df2.loc[df2['model'].isin(model_list)]
df3 = df2.loc[df2['fuel'].isin(fuel_list)]
goal = df3.iloc[0]['mpg']
print goal

for make in make_list:
    for model in model_list:
        for fuel in fuel_list:
            df1['avg'] = df1['mpg'] / goal
```

This is actually for something way bigger than this but I threw these together to demonstrate.
--Thanks - this is my first post/question so be gentle.

Comment: Edited the original - thanks again

Comment: One note: dividing observed/standard will not be an 'average' it will be a 'ratio'

Answer (score 0):

This is one way. The trick is to set indices to create and map series from one dataframe to another.

Note that your data across `df1` and `df2` appears to be perfectly aligned, so the ratio is 1.0 for every row.

```
idx = ['make', 'model', 'fuel']

s = df2.set_index(idx)['mpg'].dropna()

df1['std'] = df1.set_index(idx).index.map(s.get)
df1['ratio'] = df1['mpg'] / df1['std']

print(df1)

  state    make    model    fuel  mpg  std  ratio
0    FL   honda      fit  diesel   43   43    1.0
1    FL   honda      fit     gas   33   33    1.0
2    FL      vw     golf  diesel   48   48    1.0
3    FL      vw     golf     gas   35   35    1.0
4    FL    ford   fiesta  diesel   40   40    1.0
5    FL    ford   fiesta     gas   36   36    1.0
6    FL  toyota  corolla  diesel   44   44    1.0
7    FL  toyota  corolla     gas   38   38    1.0
```